# Is nest js make use of expreess js as a core achieving almost two times better benchmarks results.? or oly fastify to achive it

Tags: nestjs

Fastify is much faster than Express, achieving almost two times better benchmarks results.
So how they’re achieving this while keeping express as core (nestjs)?

Comment: Can you share what benchmark results you're looking at that show Nest having benchmarks at two times better than express? [Kamil posts the original benchmarks and explanations as to why express is faster here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47733390/nestjs-vs-plain-express-performance?rq=1)

Answer (score 0):

From [Performance (Fastify) in the NestJS docs](https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/performance):

"A fair question is why does Nest use Express as the default HTTP provider? The reason is that Express is widely-used, well-known, and has an enormous set of compatible middleware, which is available to Nest users out-of-the-box."

If you prefer high performance, you can follow that docs page to switch to the Fastify framework adapter.